# How can I create curl requests or in Postman (addon) for goa-cellar project

Tags: google-chrome, curl, go

I am beginner to go language. I have downloaded this project (https://github.com/goadesign/goa-cellar) and ran it in local environement. It works well when I make post,get,list calls using goa-cellar client.

**Steps**:-

1. go get github.com:goadesign/goa-cellar.git
2. goagen bootstrap -d
3. goa-cellar/design go build

**Server**:-

1. Start Server -> /.goa-cellar

Following are the sample requests which works well for me using goa-cellar client:

**Client**:-

1. Create a account -> ./cellar-cli create account /cellar/accounts --payload '{"name": "test"}'
2. List account -> ./cellar-cli list account
3. Show account -> ./cellar-cli show account /cellar/accounts/1

I want to make above request using curl or via Postman (chrome addon) or browser add on. How can I do it ?

I have tried the following:-

**1. Create account**

**Method**: POST

**URL**:- http://localhost:8082

**Request body:** {"name": "test"}

**Request headers:-** Content-Type: application/json

**Response:-**

```
{
  "code": "not_found",
  "status": 404,
  "detail": "/"
}
```

**Server log:-**

```
INFO[06-23|19:08:25] started                                  req_id=RQLpC8kzbF-2 POST=/ from=127.0.0.1 ctrl=<unknown> action=<unknown>
INFO[06-23|19:08:25] payload                                  req_id=RQLpC8kzbF-2 raw=null
INFO[06-23|19:08:25] completed                                req_id=RQLpC8kzbF-2 status=404 error=not_found bytes=47 time=97.542µs
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you already set something up using curl or Postman and it didn't work?

Comment: @MatthewBakaitis I haven't tried with curl or Postman before and update my comments in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sending data to the right HTTP API endpoint, in your case, instead this `/`, need use to `cellar/accounts` (http://localhost:8082/cellar/accounts)

By `POST` you make saving data and by `GET` + `id` - retreive data.

Look at [README](https://github.com/goadesign/goa-cellar/blob/master/README.md) for detail info for using this project.